# How can I resolve version conflict between Nodejs and NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install `purgecss` using this command:

```
npm install purgecss
```

npm returns warnings and errors

[image: Display of warnings and errors]

These are the versions.

- `NodeJs` v11.12.0
- `npm` v6.4.1

A warning states that supported releases number from 4 through 9. So, should I install a lower version of Nodejs? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for help with this.

Comment: You can use : https://github.com/creationix/nvm to install and use different version of Node. And here : https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ for the list of release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use NodeJs 11.12.0, try using `npm` 6.7.0.

My recommend is use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for Linux/MacOs or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) for Window.

It will auto download NodeJs and `npm` for you.

Comment: Thanks, Hongarc. My Win 7 machine died. I am getting a Win 10 as a replacement on 5/29. Thank you for the idea. I will try it out, soon.

Comment: Thanks, Hongarc. I used nvm-windows for Windows and can now use the command prompt to extract just the styles the app requires.

Comment: You are welcome. When you install Nodejs, it has an option to re-install `Npm`. I think you disable it so we see this error.